# Упростить выражение

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! С базы данных получаю tuple из него преобразовываю в dict и дальше в json.
Но есть данные с одинаковыми значениями только разные IP их необходимо объединить в один. Пример:

```
{'is_blocked': 0L, 'ip': '10.10.10.1', 'id': 113L}
{'is_blocked': 0L, 'ip': '10.10.10.16', 'id': 113L}
```

Нужно получить:

```
{'is_blocked': 0L, 'ip': '10.10.10.1,10.10.10.16', 'id': 113L}
```

Вопрос в какой последовательности собирать dict. Изначально не изменяемые типы tuple.

Comment: Кроме ip, остальные пары должны совпадать? (1) Этих пар всегда две? (2)

Comment: Остальные пары совподают.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ещё один вариант:

```
a=({'is_blocked': 0L, 'ip': '10.10.10.1', 'id': 113L} ,{'is_blocked': 0L, 'ip': '10.10.10.16', 'id': 113L})
r = {}
for d in a:
    if d['id'] in r:
        r[d['id']]['ip'].add(d['ip'])
    else :
        r[d['id']] = {'is_blocked':d['is_blocked'], 'ip':set((d['ip'],))}
r1 = []
for idfield in r:
        tmp = r[idfield]
        r1.append({'id':idfield, 'ip':(','.join(tuple(tmp['ip']))), 'is_blocked':tmp['is_blocked']})
print r1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(arr):
    vals, ips, res=[], [], []
    for i in arr:
        ip= i['ip']
        i2=i.copy()
        del i2['ip']
        try:
            ips[vals.index(i2)]+= ","+ip
        except:
            vals.append(i2)
            ips.append(ip)
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        vals[i]['ip']=ips[i]
        res.append(vals[i])
    return res
```

Результат на [ideone](http://ideone.com/nWS1ry) 
P.S. Если исходный массив arr далее в коде использовать не планируется, а будет работа только с преобразованным массивом, то можно немного поднять эффективность кода убрав все ссылки на `i2` заменив их на `i`, а строчку `i2=i.copy()` вообще стереть.

Answer (score 1):

Можно такую функцию родить:

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict

def group_dicts(data, key_name, joiner=None):
    """
    Groups an iterable of dictionaries on given key.
    Non-duplicate elements are joined using joiner function.

    The default implementation uses ",".join(sorted(item_set)), so beware
    that a TypeError exception may arise on non-string values.

    Pass an identity function (lambda x: x) to use sets and stay safe.

    >>> list(group_dicts([
    ...    {'id': 113, 'ip': '10.10.10.1', 'is_blocked': 0},
    ...    {'id': 114, 'ip': '10.10.10.2', 'is_blocked': 1},
    ...    {'id': 113, 'ip': '10.10.10.16', 'is_blocked': 0}
    ... ], 'ip'))
    [{'id': 113, 'ip': '10.10.10.1,10.10.10.16', 'is_blocked': 0},
     {'id': 114, 'ip': '10.10.10.2', 'is_blocked': 1}]
    """
    if joiner is None: joiner = lambda items: ",".join(sorted(items))
    keyfunc = lambda item: item[key_name]
    for _, items in groupby(sorted(data, key=keyfunc), keyfunc):
        result = defaultdict(set)
        for item in items:
            for k, v in item.items():
                result[k].add(v)
        yield {k: v.pop() if len(v) == 1 else joiner(v) for k, v in result.items()}
```

Тест-пример использования в docstring'е.

Но это некрасиво и как-то даже ресурсоемко. Я бы посмотрел, а не добавить ли `GROUP BY` (и `array_agg` (PostgreSQL)/`GROUP_CONCAT` (MySQL, Oracle)) в SQL-запрос, т.к. со стороны БД такую операцию производить как-то сподручнее.

Comment: Разве в mysql можно так объеденить?

Comment: А то! :)

См. документацию на [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), там и примеры есть.

Comment: Уже прочитал:-) из mysql логичнее будет.