# Вывод в словарь

Tags: python, django

Всем привет! Обращался за помощью [упростить выражение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/200898/python-%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), после точного формулирования в своей голове, назрел конкретный вопрос или почте)

```
            import MySQLdb
            import MySQLdb.cursors


            sql_ip_1 = """SELECT;"""
            sql_ip_2 = """SELECT;"""
            sql_ip_3 = """SELECT;"""


            def ipdict():
                db = MySQLdb.connect(cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
                cursor = db.cursor()
                cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
                cursor.execute(sql_ip_1.format('10.10.10.250'))
                for line in cursor.fetchall():
                    cursor.execute(sql_ip_2.format(line.get('id',None)))
                    for line2 in cursor.fetchall():
                        cursor.execute(sql_ip_3.format(line2.get('ip_group_id',None)))
                        for line3 in cursor.fetchall():
                            print line3,line

            ipdict()
```

[Вывод](http://pastebin.com/9ZvfyZLx) результата.

В итоге получаю словари которые необходимо сложить в мести и если id одинаковые значения тогда ip объединить в один словарь
{'ip': '10.10.10.250'} {'id': 113L}
{'ip': '10.10.10.1'} {'id': 113L}

Должно получится: {'ip': '10.10.10.250,10.10.10.1', 'id': 113L} все остальные данные убрал они находятся [Вывод](http://pastebin.com/9ZvfyZLx). Запросы итак тяжелые получаются, а их нужно еще собрать в нужный словарь и еще передать в json в веб. А может вообще и не быть словаря с IP, а просто необходимо id=113 собрать в один словарь.

Вообщем немного запутался с развязкой задачей(

Comment: Вы знает, я тоже запутался с Вашим вопросом. В первом запросе Вы делаете выборку по ip=10.10.10.250 (какой-то внутренний хост). Во-втором Вы делаете какую-то выборку по id, встречающимся в результатах первого запроса (а почему это не сделать одним select'ом?). В третьем какая-то выборка по ip_group_id из второго. Вобщем -- непонятно. Если бы Вы смогли подробней изложить задачу, возможно, были бы и подсказки, как её решить.
(И зачем три select -- тоже непонятно)

Comment: Есть биллинг UTM5, пишу запрос выборка из базы по IP и найти все его IP адреса принадлежащие ему. И потом в строчку выводим в djngo
ID|Л/С|Логин|Имя|Договор|Адрес|Телефон|Баланс|Кредит|Статус|IP

искать по IP,LOGIN,FIO
1) Искать по IP. Знаю только его IP, находим из первого запроса http://pastebin.com/SmKtsXxd все его данные, второй запрос находим какие сервисные данные принадлежат ему, третий запрос находим все IP адреса принадлежащие ему.

Comment: Ну все три запроса можно объединить в один. Вопрос, как объединять в группы. Групп должно быть (количество) столько, сколько даёт sql_ip_1? Если да, могу дать текст обобщённого запроса (на вид, правда, несколько корявый. И у меня нет Ваших таблиц, чтобы его проверить)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так (может и не напутал, таблицы создавать лениво)

```
sql_ip = """SELECT  a.ip, us.id, us.basic_account, us.login, us.full_name, us.actual_address, ROUND(ac.balance,3) AS balance,
    ac.credit, ac.is_blocked, us.work_telephone, us.home_telephone, us.mobile_telephone, us.personal_manager
    FROM ip_groups AS ipg join iptraffic_service_links AS isl on isl.ip_group_id=ipg.ip_group_id
          join service_links AS sl on sl.id=isl.id 
          join users AS us on us.id=sl.user_id
          join accounts AS ac us.basic_account=ac.id
          join (select group_concat(inet_ntoa(ipg1.ip & 0xFFFFFFFF)) ip, sl1.user_id
                from ip_groups ipg1 join service_links sl1 on ipg1.ip_group_id = sl1.ip_group_id
                     join iptraffic_service_links isl1 on isl1.id = sl1.id
                where sl1.deleted = 0 and isl1.deleted = 0 and ipg1.deleted =0
                group by sl1.user_id) a on us.id = a.user_id
    WHERE inet_ntoa(ipg.ip & 0xFFFFFFFF) LIKE '%%{0}%%' AND ipg.is_deleted=0 
          AND isl.is_deleted=0 
          AND sl.is_deleted=0 
          AND us.is_deleted=0
          AND ac.is_deleted=0"""
```